# Simplest way to implement a smart pointer vector *safely* in old C++98?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++98

Modern C++ is nice, I suppose.  It's cute that you can create a vector of smart pointers to objects with something like:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Integer>> some_integers;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Integer> new_integer = std::make_unique<Integer>();
    new_integer->SetValue(i);
    some_integers.push_back(std::move(new_integer)); 
}
```

(Integer class defined elsewhere)

But what if you're using an old C++ compiler (because you're a minimalist/Luddite) and you still want a vector of pointers that's safe against memory leaks and exceptions?  Would this suffice:

```
template <class Type>
class SmartPointerVector
{
private:
    std::vector<Type *> vect;


public:
    SmartPointerVector()
    {
    }

    ~SmartPointerVector()
    {
        while(vect.size())
        {
            delete vect.back();
            vect.pop_back();
        }
    }

    void push_back()
    {
        vect.push_back(NULL);
    }

    void set_back(Type * new_pointer)
    {
        if(vect.back())
        {
            delete vect.back();
        }
        vect.back() = new_pointer;
    }

    const std::vector<Type *> & raw() const
    {
        return vect;
    }
    std::vector<Type *> & raw()
    {
        return vect;
    }

private:
    SmartPointerVector(const SmartPointerVector & other)
    {
        assert(0);
    }

    SmartPointerVector & operator=(const SmartPointerVector & other)
    {
        assert(0);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

which could be used in old C++98 like this:

```
SmartPointerVector<Integer> some_integers;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    some_integers.push_back();
    some_integers.set_back(new Integer());
    some_integers.raw().back()->SetValue(i);
}
```

I believe this should be exception-safe as long as the `push_back()` occurs first, ensuring there is space in the vector to store the new pointer.  The subsequent call to `set_back()` should always succeed, so it should be impossible to lose/leak the new object.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html

Comment: Yep, get yourself [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html)

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr` would be an easier option. A lot of the new standard library features are available in boost in some form as many standard library features started life in boost

Comment: I do not understand why the question starts off the way it does. Also, the entire body of the for loop could just be `some_integers.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(/* your value */));`. Surely the minimalist in you will appreciate how much more compact modern C++ makes your code.

Comment: Old way to mark function as `= delete` was declare them without definition, definition with `assert(0);` is unneeded.

Comment: You are asking for a C++98 solution but tag your question c++11!?